# i don't think i understand function enclosures

Tags: r

I'm trying to package some code I use for data analysis so that other workers can use it. Currently, I'm stuck trying to write a simple function that imports data from a specific file type generated by a datalogger and trims it for use by other functions. Here's the code:

```
import<-function(filename,type="campbell",nprobes){
  if (filename==TRUE){
    if (type=="campbell"){
      message("File import type is from Campbell CR1000")
      flux.data<<-read.table(filename,sep=",",header=T,skip=1) 
      flux.data<<-flux.data[,-c(1,2)];flux.data<<-flux.data[-c(1,2),] 
      if (nprobes=="missing"){
        nprobes<-32
      }
      flux.data<<-flux.data[,c(1:nprobes)]
      flux.data.names<<-colnames(flux.data) #Saves column names
    }
  }
}
```

Ideally, the result would be a dataframe/matrix `flux.data` and a concomittant vector/list of the preserved column headers `flux.data.names`. The code runs and the function executes without errors, but the outputs aren't preserved. I usually use `<<-` to get around the function enclosure but its not working in this case - any suggestions?

I think the real problem is that I don't quite understand how enclosures work, despite a lot of reading... should I be using `environment` to assign environments within the function?

Comment: Are you sure that `filename == TRUE` does what you think it does? Also, is it really necessary to use `<<-`? Why not just have the function return the trimmed data?

Comment: 1) No, I'm not sure... removing that part fixed the problem. I think I was trying to build in an if-else that I could expand on later, and wrote that to see if `filename` existed. I'm guessing as its written it is looking for an exact match. 2) It looks like it is - I took out the `<<-` and replaced it with `<-` and it won't return the trimmed data, which is what I was trying to do. Is there another way to get it to return trimmed data besides `<<-`? 3) The spaces in the `message` line don't seem to matter, I commented that out and it didn't change anything.

Comment: So you use `return()` to explicitly return objects from functions. I don't see much need to return the column names separately, since they are already in the data, but you could return a list with both the data and the column names as separate list elements.

Comment: ...and of course then the usage of the function would require explicit assignment, e.g. `my_data <- import(...)`.

Comment: Wow, that makes a lot of sense. Assigning/calling the function (`my_data<-import(...)`) within another function would then make the data available within that enclosure?

Comment: Yes, and I think the terminology you're looking for is that functions (aka closures) have environments in which their code is executed. So `my_data` would be available in the local environment created for the execution of that function. (It is more complicated than that, but then we'd have to have a long conversation about scope.)

Comment: Man, that is super helpful! One last thing - how do I give you credit for answering my question with a comment?

Comment: Ask him to write up his comments as an answer.  If he can't be bothered/doesn't get around to it in a day or so, write up the answer yourself and credit him in the text of your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User joran answered my question in the comments above:

The critical issue was just in how the function was written: the conditional at the start (`if filename==TRUE`) was intended to see if filename was specified, and instead was checking to see if it literally equaled `TRUE`. The result was the conditional never being met, and no function output. Here's what fixed it:

```
import<-function(filename,type="campbell",nprobes){
  if (exists(filename){
    if (type=="campbell"){
#etc....
```

Another cool thing he pointed out was that I didn't need the `<<-` operator to utilize the function output and instead could write `return(flux.data)`. This is a much more flexible approach, and helped me understand function enclosures a lot better.

Comment: Since you don't have a contingency case if there isn't a filename something like `if (!exists(filename)) stop("filename must be specified")` might be more user-friendly.